# how to define different expression for each region(domain) in a function in wolfram alpha

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I want to write the following function to wolframalpha

[image: math equations]

which means this function is defined by a different expression for x<0, 0<=x<=1 and x>1 by the expression above.

[i found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087461/how-to-specify-domain-of-a-function-in-wolfram-alpha) which Brought me closer to the answer but not yet. 
`f(x,y) = cos(1/x) for x<0` , how to continue for the two different parts?

by the way, using [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) I could generate LATEX representation for this equation from the photo which wolfram should understand, but apparently not when splitting the function for different expression per domain...

how can I write this function to wolframAlpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
plot Piecewise[{{cos(1/x),x<0},{sin(pi x),0<=x<=1},{2^-x,x>1}}] for -1<x<2
```

[WA page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Piecewise%5B%7B%7Bcos%281%2Fx%29%2Cx%3C0%7D%2C%7Bsin%28pi+x%29%2C0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%7D%2C%7B2%5E-x%2Cx%3E1%7D%7D%5D+for+-1%3Cx%3C2)